# Bootstrap CSS classes wildcard

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to target all of the columns inside a Bootstrap container so I can give then a similar style. For example:

```
<div class="container unique">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can target this with CSS:

```
.unique .col-md-3{...}
```

but what I want to do is when I have many different `col-*` elements, to target them all together.

I tried this:

```
.unique .col-*{...}
```

but it didn't work.  Can I do this with CSS?

Comment: .unique  [class^="col-"] 
This one worked for me.

Comment: [class*="col-"] { border-color: red;}

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Pedro, what you're looking for is called [**attribute selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). In your particular case, you can use it like this:

```
.unique [class~=col] {color:red }
```

but you could also use this with more wide options like

```
[class*='col-']
```

to cover preceding white spaces.

Also, here you have the [same documentation in Spanish](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Selectores_atributo)

Comment: The first selector won't match the columns, the second one may or may not. http://jsbin.com/rajaw/1/edit

Comment: According to the linked documentation, the 100% correct form that matches the pattern in question is `.unique [class^=col-] {color: red}`

Comment: Keep in mind, you select all classes which begin with col-. That includes col-md-offset-...

Answer (score 19):

The CSS attribute contains selector can be used to achieve this:

```
.unique [class*=col]{...}
```

MDN is a useful reference site for CSS selectors. For reference, the attribute selectors are found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).