# How to set all bootstrap columns within all containers with a border for visual planning purposes only

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

How to set all bootstrap columns within all containers with a border for visual planning purposes only

I want to simply turn on all borders for all my different columns just during development so I can the cells for visual design purposes only. Is there an easy way to do this

Or is there a better way where I can my container grid's cells layout ?

Comment: Is the question how to apply css styles only in development environment or how to apply style to all bootstrap columns? If it's the second you can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25954181/bootstrap-css-classes-wildcard).

Answer (score 0):

> I want to simply turn on all borders for all my different columns just
> during development so I can the cells for visual design purposes only.
> Is there an easy way to do this?

Well, based on your question, its appeard that, we know the `container column class name`and the `Environment` if this is the scenario then there is an easiest way to achieve your expectations.

**Retrive Environment Variable:**

Firstly, we would check the `Environment Variable` by simply following `code snippet`

```cs
 var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
```

**Check The Environment:**

Now we know the `app environment` therefore, we could check it by a simple `conditionals` as following

```cs
@{
    var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
    if (env == "Development")
    {

    }

}
```

**Manipulateb Your DOM:**

```cs
@{
    var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
    if (env == "Development")
    {

    @section Scripts{

    <script type="text/javascript">
                alert('@env')
                $(".col").css({ "border": "Solid red 2px" });
    </script>

    }
    }

}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">Left column</div>
        <div class="col">Middle column</div>
        <div class="col">Right column</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** This is the most easy and simplest way to achieve that.Hope you will found it helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Environment Tag Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/environment-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to apply styles only in development environment.

`_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<head>
    ...
    ...
    <environment include="Development">
        <style>
            [class^="col"] {
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
        </style>
    </environment>
</head>
```